# Calling a No Await Function inside Azure Function

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

Is it okay to call an async function inside Azure Function without await on that function?

This is actually working on my end although I have to simplify the code it here. getData() terminates ahead of runInBackground(). After a few seconds, runInBackground finishes.

However, it's in MS Azure docs to implement await, but not sure if this scenario is covered. Given the use case of runInBackground, is this acceptable and what possible issues could arise with this implementation?

**handler azure function**

```
export const getData: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest,
): Promise<void> {
  try {
    // really need to wait for this
    const data = await service.getData(...);

    // no need to wait, no await
    runInBackground();

    context.res = handleResp(data);
  } catch (e) {
    context.res = handleErr(e);
  }
};
```

**a function that is intended to run separately (sort of fire and forget). no need to know the results.**

```
export const runInBackground = async () => {
  const url = `https://externalapi/call`;

  try {
     await axios.post(url, {});
  } catch (error) {
     console.log(error.response);
  }
};
```

Edit: Will there be any possibility that the runInBackground() process gets terminated/dropped after getData() has successfully returned response? I actually tested this and there is no issue -- it proceeds. I'd just like to know though if this is a hit or miss kind of. And if there is a documentation on this.

Comment: You wont notice errors if `runInBackground` starts to fail. No more issues I think

Comment: @Rashomon yeah that's find. Would you happen to know if the background process would be dropped/terminated after getData has successfully executed? Or will runInBackground() would continue running? I tried it and so far, it runs until it finishes. But if someone can give me a reference to this.

Comment: Sorry just noticed your `console.log(error.response);`. So yes, your process should be active and log the error if it fails. As long as you have callbacks or promises that resolve, Node will wait for them. Found an interesting thread in github about it https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22088#issuecomment-409966419. Seems like Node does not wait for ever-pending promises (promises without callbacks and resolve function)

Comment: Returning a promise will not work. I tried it as well. But, I do not need to return a Promise. This is why in Azure docs, they recommend await in combo with try catch.

Comment: we have exactly this problem, we fired `axios.post(otherHttpTriggeredFunctionUrl)` without awaiting it. And when the otherHttpTriggeredFunction failed or it took it too long our original function started to fail with unhandled exception. Then we added `.catch()` and caught the error. So I don't know what's going on there but looks like it is not really fire and forget in Azure Functions environment even though Node.js does not wait for ever-pending Promises.